# ssh - execute script in background if not already running?

Tags: ssh, python, cron

How do I execute a python script in the background if it is not already running? An example use for this is on the cron.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a script to start once at startup and theoretically it stays up then you should add it as a service to init.d with the appropriate runlevel set.

Of course if it should go down then you would want to to come back up.

to do that you can have a shell script run ps -aux | grep 'nameOfYourScript' like that. Of course don't include the grep command which will match as well lol.
have that script check every five minutes  with a cron like this 
*/5  * * * * user checkScript.sh

the checkScript you make could be written to start up the program.

Comment: More generally: there is no foolproof method to check if a program is already running.  Search this site with keywords such as `daemontools`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# count the number of processes that match "NameOfProcess" but 
# exclude the grep process itself
pc=`ps -ef |grep "NameOfProcess" |grep -v grep |wc -l`

# if pc > 0, the process is already running and we can exit.
if [ $pc -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo "Application is already running, exiting."
    exit 0
fi

# othewise start the program
/path/to/program
```

Put this in crontab or start with

```
nohup /path/to/script.sh &
```

nohup will make sure that the process isnt shutdown if you exit the ssh session. An alternative to this is `screen`

Comment: I'd pick `nohup` over `screen` myself, but whatever works, works.